# Handling parameters in a form without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have a "show" action processing two parameters "a" and "b". There is no model involved. Now I am creating a view with a form for this with two fields (a,b). After submitting it the "show" function should be called with the entered values as parameters.

A. How do I setup the form correctly in order to connect it to the show function and set the two parameters? I tried the following.

> ```
> <%= form_tag( :action => 'show', :method => :get) do %>
> <p>
> <%= label :First, :A %><br />
> <%= text_field :First, :A %></p>
> <p>
> <%= label :Second, :B %><br />
> <%= text_field :Second, :B %></p>
> <p>
> <%= submit_tag 'Set' %></p>
> <% end %>
> ```

It doesn't seem to work. the show action is not called an no parameter is transferred.

B. How do I address the parameters coming from the form within the action? Currently I get them only from the URL by `params[:a]` and `params[:b]`. The form should be an additional way to set those values for the "show" function.

Comment: Seems like I got the form_tag wrong. using `<%= form_tag( {:action => 'show'}, {:method => :get}) do %>` works better but now I get a puzzling `show?utf8=✓&%3Aa%5Ba%5D=23&commit=Set` in the url. How can I fix the utf8.. part?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is accurate except for the case-sensitive variable names. Lowercase :A and :B to make it work.

Comment: I changed it to `<%= label :First, :a %><br /><%= text_field :First, :a %>`. It still does not work. The problem seems to be that the resulting URL ends with `show?method=get` not `show?a=23&b=21`